# REGEXP_SUBSTR desired output

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('one,two,three',',[^,]+') AS reg_result FROM DUAL;

REG_RESULT    
,two          

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('eight,nineteen,five',',[^,]+') AS reg_result FROM DUAL;  

REG_RESULT    
,nineteen
```

I have to *remove the " , " from the result*. Also I *want the last string 
as the output*. i.e. *three* from 'one,two,three' & *five* from 'eight,nineteen,five'.
 How can I do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to just get the last word without checking if your string meets particular pattern:

```
SQL> with t1 as(
  2    select 'one,two,three' as str from dual
  3  )
  4  select regexp_substr(str, '([[:alpha:]]+)$') last_word
  5    from t1
  6  ;

LAST_WORD
---------
three
```

---

**Response to the comment**

> how to get string two from the first one & nineteen from the second??

Fourth parameter of the `regexp_substr` function is the occurrence of a pattern.  So to get the second word in the string we can use `regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, 2)`

```
SQL> with t1 as(
  2        select 'one,two,three' as str from dual
  3      )
  4  select regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, 2) as Second_Word
  5       from t1;

Second_Word
---------
two
```

If there is a need to extract every word from your strings:

```
-- sample of data from your question
SQL> with t1 as(
  2     select 'one,two,three' as str from dual union all
  3     select 'eight,nineteen,five' from dual
  4  ), -- occurrences of the pattern
  5  occurrence as(
  6   select level as ps
  7     from ( select max(regexp_count(str, '[^,]+')) mx
  8              from t1
  9           ) s
 10    connect by level <= s.mx
 11  ) -- the query
 12  select str
 13       , regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, o.ps) word
 14       , o.ps as word_num
 15    from t1 t
 16     cross join occurrence o
 17  order by str
 18  ;

STR                  WORD          WORD_NUM
-------------------  ----------- ----------
eight,nineteen,five  eight                1
eight,nineteen,five  nineteen             2
eight,nineteen,five  five                 3
one,two,three        three                3
one,two,three        one                  1
one,two,three        two                  2

6 rows selected
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. how to get string **two** from the first one & **nineteen** from the second??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('one,two,three',',[^,]+$'),'[^,]+') AS reg_result FROM DUAL;
```

I'm not certain if Oracle has lookbehinds, but you can try this as well:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('one,two,three','(?<=,)[^,]+$') AS reg_result FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('one,two,three','[^,]+$') AS reg_result FROM DUAL;                                                        REG_RESULT
three` removing the first comma. thank you for the reply. what about my first query??

Comment: @sam The answer I have posted solves both problems. See this demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/4497/0